# How do I format JSON's with multiple of the same keys with python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a program that right now grabs data like temperature and loads using a powershell script and the WMI. It outputs the data as a JSON file. Now let me preface this by saying this is my first time every working with JSON's and im not very familiar with the JSON python library. Here is the code to my program:

```
import subprocess
import json

p = subprocess.Popen(["C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe", ". \"./TestScript\";", "&NSV"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
(output, err) = p.communicate()

data = json.loads(output)

for mNull in data:
    del mNull['Scope']
    del mNull['Path']
    del mNull['Options']
    del mNull['ClassPath']
    del mNull['Properties']
    del mNull['SystemProperties']
    del mNull['Qualifiers']
    del mNull['Site']
    del mNull['Container']
    del mNull['PSComputerName']
    del mNull['__GENUS']
    del mNull['__CLASS']
    del mNull['__SUPERCLASS']
    del mNull['__DYNASTY']
    del mNull['__RELPATH']
    del mNull['__PROPERTY_COUNT']
    del mNull['__DERIVATION']
    del mNull['__SERVER']
    del mNull['__NAMESPACE']
    del mNull['__PATH']

fdata = json.dumps(data,indent=2)

print(fdata)
```

Now here is the resulting JSON:

```
[
  {
    "Name": "Memory",
    "SensorType": "Load",
    "Value": 53.3276978
  },
  {
    "Name": "CPU Core #2",
    "SensorType": "Temperature",
    "Value": 69
  },
  {
    "Name": "Used Space",
    "SensorType": "Load",
    "Value": 93.12801
  },
  {
    "Name": "CPU Core #1",
    "SensorType": "Temperature",
    "Value": 66
  },
  {
    "Name": "CPU DRAM",
    "SensorType": "Power",
    "Value": 1.05141532
  },
  {
    "Name": "CPU Core #2",
    "SensorType": "Load",
    "Value": 60.15625
  },
  {
    "Name": "CPU Package",
    "SensorType": "Power",
    "Value": 15.2162886
  },
  {
    "Name": "Bus Speed",
    "SensorType": "Clock",
    "Value": 100.000031
  },
  {
    "Name": "CPU Total",
    "SensorType": "Load",
    "Value": 57.421875
  },
  {
    "Name": "CPU Package",
    "SensorType": "Temperature",
    "Value": 69
  },
  {
    "Name": "CPU Core #2",
    "SensorType": "Clock",
    "Value": 2700.00073
  },
  {
    "Name": "Temperature",
    "SensorType": "Temperature",
    "Value": 41
  },
  {
    "Name": "Used Memory",
    "SensorType": "Data",
    "Value": 4.215393
  },
  {
    "Name": "Available Memory",
    "SensorType": "Data",
    "Value": 3.68930435
  },
  {
    "Name": "CPU Core #1",
    "SensorType": "Clock",
    "Value": 3100.001
  },
  {
    "Name": "CPU Cores",
    "SensorType": "Power",
    "Value": 13.3746643
  },
  {
    "Name": "CPU Graphics",
    "SensorType": "Power",
    "Value": 0.119861834
  },
  {
    "Name": "CPU Core #1",
    "SensorType": "Load",
    "Value": 54.6875
  }
]
```

As you can see every dictionary in the list has the keys `Name`, `SensorType` and `Value`.

What I want to do is make it so that each list has a "label" equal to the `Name` in each one, so I can call for data from specific entries, one at a time. Once again, I'm kind of a newbie with JSON and its library so I'm not even sure if this sort of thing is possible. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Have a good day! :)

Edit 1:
Here is an example, using the first 2, of what I would like the program to be able to output.

```
[
  "Memory":{
    "SensorType": "Load",
    "Value": 53.3276978
  },
  "CPU Core #2":{
    "SensorType": "Temperature",
    "Value": 69
  }
]
```

Once again, I dont even know if this is valid JSON but I want it to just do something at least similar to that so I can call, for example, `print(data["Memory"]["Value"])` and return, `53.3276978`.

Edit 2:
It did just occur to me that there are some names with multiple sensor types, for example, `"CPU Core #1"` and `"CPU Core #2"` both have `"Tempurature"`, `"Load"`, and `"Clock"`. Using the above example could cause some conflicts so is there a way we could account for that?

Comment: Not clear what you're asking.  You can get, e.g., the "Name" value from the first item by doing `data[0]["Name"]`.  Is that what you want?

Comment: Don't worry about the Python `json` library, or about JSON in general. Just worry about properly building the dicts/lists/whatever you want properly, and then the only thing you need to add for JSON is calling `json.dumps` to convert the top-level thing to a string to send it over the wire or save in a file or whatever, and `json.loads` to turn that string back to the thing.

Comment: @BrenBarn What i need to do is take the `0`, `1`, `2` ... and set them each to `"Name"` without getting rid of the other data.

Comment: Is there a naming convention you are talking about? or do you want to add an extra label on the top of the existing one? can you show the output you expect?

Comment: I edited the post with what I would like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you need to keep the values if key already exists:

```
import json
data = [
{
    "Name": "Memory",
    "SensorType": "Load",
    "Value": 53.3276978
},
{
    "Name": "CPU Core #2",
    "SensorType": "Temperature",
    "Value": 69
},
{
    "Name": "Used Space",
    "SensorType": "Load",
    "Value": 93.12801
},
{
    "Name": "CPU Core #1",
    "SensorType": "Temperature",
    "Value": 66
},
{
    "Name": "CPU DRAM",
    "SensorType": "Power",
    "Value": 1.05141532
},
{
    "Name": "CPU Core #2",
    "SensorType": "Load",
    "Value": 60.15625
},
{
    "Name": "CPU Package",
    "SensorType": "Power",
    "Value": 15.2162886
},
{
    "Name": "Bus Speed",
    "SensorType": "Clock",
    "Value": 100.000031
},
{
    "Name": "CPU Total",
    "SensorType": "Load",
    "Value": 57.421875
},
{
    "Name": "CPU Package",
    "SensorType": "Temperature",
    "Value": 69
},
{
    "Name": "CPU Core #2",
    "SensorType": "Clock",
    "Value": 2700.00073
},
{
    "Name": "Temperature",
    "SensorType": "Temperature",
    "Value": 41
},
{
    "Name": "Used Memory",
    "SensorType": "Data",
    "Value": 4.215393
},
{
    "Name": "Available Memory",
    "SensorType": "Data",
    "Value": 3.68930435
},
{
    "Name": "CPU Core #1",
    "SensorType": "Clock",
    "Value": 3100.001
},
{
    "Name": "CPU Cores",
    "SensorType": "Power",
    "Value": 13.3746643
},
{
    "Name": "CPU Graphics",
    "SensorType": "Power",
    "Value": 0.119861834
},
{
    "Name": "CPU Core #1",
    "SensorType": "Load",
    "Value": 54.6875
}
]

final_data = {}

for d in data:
    if d['Name'] not in final_data:
        final_data[d['Name']] = list()

    key = d.pop('Name')
    final_data[key].append(temp)


print json.dumps(final_data,indent=4)
```

will give you

```
{
"CPU Package": [
    {
        "SensorType": "Power",
        "Value": 15.2162886
    },
    {
        "SensorType": "Temperature",
        "Value": 69
    }
],
"Temperature": [
    {
        "SensorType": "Temperature",
        "Value": 41
    }
],
"CPU Core #2": [
    {
        "SensorType": "Temperature",
        "Value": 69
    },
    {
        "SensorType": "Load",
        "Value": 60.15625
    },
    {
        "SensorType": "Clock",
        "Value": 2700.00073
    }
],
"CPU Core #1": [
    {
        "SensorType": "Temperature",
        "Value": 66
    },
    {
        "SensorType": "Clock",
        "Value": 3100.001
    },
    {
        "SensorType": "Load",
        "Value": 54.6875
    }
],
"CPU Cores": [
    {
        "SensorType": "Power",
        "Value": 13.3746643
    }
],
"Available Memory": [
    {
        "SensorType": "Data",
        "Value": 3.68930435
    }
],
"Used Space": [
    {
        "SensorType": "Load",
        "Value": 93.12801
    }
],
"Bus Speed": [
    {
        "SensorType": "Clock",
        "Value": 100.000031
    }
],
"Memory": [
    {
        "SensorType": "Load",
        "Value": 53.3276978
    }
],
"Used Memory": [
    {
        "SensorType": "Data",
        "Value": 4.215393
    }
],
"CPU Total": [
    {
        "SensorType": "Load",
        "Value": 57.421875
    }
],
"CPU DRAM": [
    {
        "SensorType": "Power",
        "Value": 1.05141532
    }
],
"CPU Graphics": [
    {
        "SensorType": "Power",
        "Value": 0.119861834
    }
]
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You can build a new dictionary in the shape you want like this:

```
...
data = {
    element["Name"]: {
        key: value for key, value in element.items() if key != "Name"
    }
    for element in json.loads(output)
}
fdata = json.dumps(data, indent=4)
...
```

Result:

```
{
    "Memory": {
        "SensorType": "Load",
        "Value": 53.3276978
    },
    "CPU Core #2": {
        "SensorType": "Clock",
        "Value": 2700.00073
    },
    (and so on)
}
```

Comment: I get an error saying `NameError: name 'element' is not defined`

Comment: There was a typo introduced while making the code more readable, which was fixed by janbrohl. You should no longer get the error.

Answer (score 0):

```
x="""[
  {
    "Name": "Memory 1",
    "SensorType": "Load",
    "Value": 53.3276978
  },
  {
    "Name": "CPU Core #2",
    "SensorType": "Load",
    "Value": 53.3276978
  }]"""

json_obj=json.loads(x)

new_list=[]
for item in json_obj:
    name=item.pop('Name')
    new_list.append({name:item})

print(json.dumps(new_list,indent=4))
```

Output

```
[
{
    "Memory 1": {
        "SensorType": "Load", 
        "Value": 53.3276978
    }
}, 
{
    "CPU Core #2": {
        "SensorType": "Load", 
        "Value": 53.3276978
    }
}
]
```

Comment: From JSON perspective `"{u'SensorType': u'Load', u'Value': 53.3276978}"` is just a single string

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
import json
orig_list = json.load(<filename>)
new_dict = { l['Name']:{k:v for k,v in l.items() if k!='Name'} for l in orig_list}
json.dumps(new_dict, <filename>)
```

This way, you won't have to `del` items from the `dict`s that you load from the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can just replace

```
for mNull in data:
    del mNull['Scope']
    del mNull['Path']
    del mNull['Options']
    del mNull['ClassPath']
    del mNull['Properties']
    del mNull['SystemProperties']
    del mNull['Qualifiers']
    del mNull['Site']
    del mNull['Container']
    del mNull['PSComputerName']
    del mNull['__GENUS']
    del mNull['__CLASS']
    del mNull['__SUPERCLASS']
    del mNull['__DYNASTY']
    del mNull['__RELPATH']
    del mNull['__PROPERTY_COUNT']
    del mNull['__DERIVATION']
    del mNull['__SERVER']
    del mNull['__NAMESPACE']
    del mNull['__PATH']

fdata = json.dumps(data,indent=2)
```

with

```
dontwant=set(['Name', 'PSComputerName', '__RELPATH', '__DYNASTY', '__CLASS', '__PROPERTY_COUNT', 'Site', 'ClassPath', 'SystemProperties', 'Scope', 'Qualifiers', 'Options', '__NAMESPACE', 'Path', '__SUPERCLASS', '__DERIVATION', '__GENUS', '__PATH', 'Container', 'Properties', '__SERVER']) # set of keys to drop
out={} # empty dict
for mNull in data:
    name=mNull['Name']
    out[name]={key:value for key,value in mNull.items() if key not in dontwant} # only copy over items you want

fdata = json.dumps(out,indent=2)
```